# Strings with special characters

Tags: python, special-characters, komodo

I have to check for the presence of a substring in a string in python. The problem comes from the fact that the substring contains a special character.

I am reading a feature from a csv file. The feature is a distance with numbers and its units:

```
12.4 miles
34 Kilómetros
800 metros
```

I have to read the feature, check the units and convert to metres.

```
for line in filename:
    if 'miles' in line:  #checking for miles is straight forward
       #do whatever I have to do
    if 'Kilómetros' in line:  #the problem is here
       #do whatever I have to do
```

Komodo will not let me save my .py file because of the special character in `Kilómetros`. Any help? Even if Komodo let me save the file, would this work?

Comment: What do you mean, it won't let you save your file? How is it stopping you? Does it give you an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: Default encoding for strings in Python 3.x is **utf-8** so the code is valid. There may be an encoding option in Komodo's configuration menu where you could force utf-8

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it Sciroccorics. I forced the file encoding to utf-8 in Edit | Current File Preferences | Encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komodo attempts to detect and set which encoding your file is using when the file is first opened.  It might have missed the mark.  You can see which encoding Komodo chose in the status bar at the top of the text editing area.  Click the drop down to change it.

[image: Encoding Settings in Komodo. Note screen shot is from IDE but Encoding drop down is in the same location.]

For future Komodo questions you should use the [Komodo Forums](https://community.komodoide.com/).

Comment: Thank yo very much. That was it, I forced it to UTF-8 encoding in Edit | Current File Preferences | Encoding. I apologize for posting the question in this forum. I failed at realizing the problem was caused by Komodo, I thought it was python  having problems with the special characters and komodo was just signaling the problem. sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: No problem at all. You're allowed to ask Komodo questions here. I'm just saying that if you have them in the future, we (we being the devs) are really active in our forums. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score -2):

Do the exact opposite. Check if all the characters are in a list you want. e.g.

```
text1 = 'abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc'
for char in text1:
    if char not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
       print('oops',text1)
text2 = 'abcabcabcabcaΞΞΞbcabcabcabcabcabc'
for char in text2:
    if char not in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
       print('oops',text2)
```

Comment: the problem is not in the code, its a problem with the editor not picking the right encoding!